# SWIFT 3 OSX Cocoa Array Controller and CoreData Binding "Search on multiple columns"

Tags: swift, cocoa, nstableview, nsarraycontroller, nssearchfield

I have a coredata entity bound to a tableView with 5 columns.
I am using an array controller for managing the tableview sorting etc.

My issue is with searching using the bindings. I have a searchField bound to the ArrayController and the predicate format is set to the first column of data. Everything works fine. I can also change the predicate format in XCODE and search on a different column.

The problem I am having is knowing how the change the predicate format in my code to allow the user to search on a column of their choice...

I have attempted modifying the ArrayController as follows:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "projectNumber contains[cd] %@", searchBar.stringValue)
    searchArrayController.filterPredicate = predicate
```

AND

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "customerName contains[cd] %@", searchBar.stringValue)
    searchArrayController.filterPredicate = predicate
```

projectNumber and customerName are attributes of my entity.

When I set the predicate this way the table data vanishes. I am able to get it to show again with fiddling of the search field but it ignores my predicate settings and only obeys the original one set in the XCODE storyboard.

StoryBoard setting is:
Predicate Format = projectNumber contains[cd] $value

thank you in advance for any help you can provide...

Comment: Forgot to mention that the predicate settings are in the bindings inspector of the searchField where I bind it to the ArrayController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a predicate binding for each column. When you bind `predicate` of the search field, a binding `predicate2` appears. No coding required.

Comment: For anyone who comes across this looking for how to select columns to search at runtime. Apple has provided a search menu popup using NSMenu and the ability to set a predicate for each column that are set in the bindings panel of Xcode... maybe not the best possible way to present column search choices in my opinion, I would like a little more flexibility in the presentation, but it is at least very easy to implement....